# Find an interval over which a continuous function is strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and weakly increasing function. Suppose $f$ is not a constant. Can we conclude that there exists $0 \leq \alpha < \beta \leq 1$ such that $f$ is strictly increasing over $(\alpha, \beta)$?

This result seems to me intuitive, but I do not know how to prove it formally. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What's weakly increasing function?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude that there is such an interval. Look up [devil's staircase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395960/cantor-function-strictly-increasing

Comment: @asdf It means $f(t) \geq f(s)$ if $t > s$. Strictly increasing function means $f(t) > f(s)$ if $t > s$.