# Optimization with strictly increasing continuous function with zero derivative (a.e.)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Suppose we have a strictly increasing, continuous scalar variable function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x) = 0 \text{ a.e.}$ The problem is $$\underset{x \in [a, b]}{\max}\ f(x) - cx$$ for some positive $c$. Since we have a sum of two continuous functions, it follows from the Weirstrass theorem that there exists a solution. If solution is interior, we cannot find it from the first order condition since $f'(x) = 0 \text{ a.e}$.

My question is: are there ways to characterize the interior solution analytically in general (without specifying $f(x)$)? I am also interested in a more general setting, where instead of $-cx$ there could be any continuous function.

If you have references to papers which study this, would be very grateful if you share.

Comment: Interesting question. Obviously, you need to know something more about $f$ to have any chance of solving it. For a given $a, b, c, f(a), f(b)$, you can choose $\epsilon > 0$ and either $f$ constant on $[a+\epsilon, b]$ and to raise Cantor-style on $[a, a+\epsilon]$, or else choose $f$ constant on $[a, b-\epsilon]$ and raising Cantor-style on $[b-\epsilon, b]$ to have any maximum value in $(f(a) - cb, f(b) - ca)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I mentioned strictly increasing function, so it will not be a constant on any interval. I understand that we can always find such functions where any maximum value is possible; I am interested in the ways of finding and characterizing this maximum value. For example, if f(x) is absolutely continuous it is also true that we can find a function for any possible maximum value, but for any such a function we have a way of characterizing a solution (FOC, SOC). I am wondering if there are some methods for the case I've described.

Comment: "(FOC, SOC)" means?

Comment: @PaulSinclair First/Second order conditions, sorry for that, probably I should have not used the abbreviations.

Comment: Still not familar with what you are referring to. But that is an aside. Do you have a proof of existence for strictly increasing functions with $f' = 0$ a.e.? The Cantor function is mostly constant, and when I consider methods to address that, they do not converge to something with $f' = 0$ a.e.

Comment: Never mind. I found one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250628/constructing-a-strictly-increasing-function-with-zero-derivatives).