# Construction of a no constant but vanishing derivative function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a problem from Rudin RCA 7.7: 
Construct a continuous monotonic function $f$ on $\Bbb R^{1}\equiv\Bbb R$ so that $f$ is not constant on any segment although $f^{'}(x)=0$ $m$-a.e.

Some of my thoughts:
I consider the function $F(x)$=$m([0,x] \cap$ A) for measurable set A,then we have:

1. $F^{'}(x)=1$ a.e. on $A$
2. $F^{'}(x)=0$ a.e. on $A^{c}$.

However, if $m(A)=0$, then $F$ is constant on any segment; if $m(A)\neq 0$, then $F^{'}(x)$ can not be zero  a.e. on $\Bbb R$.
This makes me confused, thanks for your help!

There is a similar problem here, however how to variant it to the whole $R$?
[Constructing a strictly increasing function with zero derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250628/constructing-a-strictly-increasing-function-with-zero-derivatives)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a strictly increasing function with zero derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250628/constructing-a-strictly-increasing-function-with-zero-derivatives)

Comment: @r9m emmm...I think this solution may not be the answer Ruin wanted cause Cantor-Vitali function has not be taken in his book....

Comment: I don't know any examples which are intrinsically different from the Cantor function .. only linked for reference. :)

Comment: @r9m, this example does not satisfie cause this is not defined on R...

Comment: *this example does not satisfie cause this is not defined on R* --- Have you ever heard the phrase "extend by periodicity" or a similar such phrase? This is a fairly well known notion in analysis. Not that anyone would expect you to have seen this, but note that Rudin himself uses (essentially) this phrase [in this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-02/S0002-9939-1964-0159918-8/S0002-9939-1964-0159918-8.pdf) (p. 321, line -3): "... and define $f(x)$ for all other $x$ by periodicity".